# the data is changed, but reloading does not fetch new data, D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I load my data in D3 with the d3.csv() function. When I change the CSV file and reload the http page, it still uses the old data. How can I get D3 to use the new data in de CSV file instead of the old data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like caching issue. Add a cache buster to it i.e, append some random string to your url.

```
d3.csv('/getdata?_=' + new Date().getTime())
```

By using this, browser will not be able to identify similarity of requests.

Comment: Thanks this helped. I didn't figure out your specific solution but I did this:  
         d3.csv('data.csv?t=${Date.now()}', function(data) {             Also I just figured out I can't write a code block in a reply. thats too bad.